# how to AutoFilter data when Criteria filter values are missing sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code where I want to filter data based on whether the column contains one of these values ("A", "B", "G", "P", "L", "M", "C", "H", "K", "T", "W", "E", "N", "S", "D", "X", "U", "F"). But sometimes the column does not have one of these values (for example, in one project, there is no data with "N" and "L"). In that case, the program gives me an error. How do I fix this?

My code is the following:

```
    Set sh = wbmain.Worksheets("depth")
    
    sh.Range("A1:J" & sh.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "A", "B", "G", "P", "L", "M", "C", "H", "K", "T", "W", "E", "N", "S", "D", "X", "U", "F"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    
    sh.Range("C1:I" & sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

I am thinking an on error resume next might work but I am unsure how to implement it as if there is an error with let's say "M", then it will just skip everything after "M" (and not filter "C", "H", "K", "T", "W", "E", "N", "S", "D", "X", "U", "F")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `OERN` and `If` clause to avoid runtime error

```vb
    Set sh = wbmain.Worksheets("depth")
    sh.Range("A1:J" & sh.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "A", "B", "G", "P", "L", "M", "C", "H", "K", "T", "W", "E", "N", "S", "D", "X", "U", "F"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    Dim visRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = sh.Range("C1:I" & sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then visRng.Select
```

It's worth to read:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)